# How to query 'sell' attribute of rails model with groupdate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Price model that has a buy and a sell attribute. I am trying to graph this, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the query I need.

I need the final hash to be `:created_at => :SELL/BUY_ATTRIBUTE`

I'm using the groupdate gem to try and get it by minute, but the following doesn't work: `Price.group_by_minute(:created_at).pluck(:buy)`

The only examples of group_by_X I can find appends it with a `.count`, never anything else.

Comment: why exactly doesn't this work? what is the data structure that is returned or the error received?

Comment: @maxpleaner I get the following error: ```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "price_btcs.buy" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "price_btcs"."buy" FROM "price_btcs" WHERE (created_a...```

Comment: When grouping you must add the id from table being used, in this case if btc is the primary key, then it'd be `Price.group(:id, :created_at)`, I don't know if group_by_minute does the same as group.

Comment: I guess something like `Price.select(:buy, :sell, :created_at).group_by(&:created_at)` would work, but you would have to handle a hash with very ugly keys.

Comment: I think you are interested in an aggregation anyway like maybe the average buying price every minute. otherwise grouping makes no sense. You could either use `Price.group_by_minute(:created_at).average(:buy)` for the average buying price every minute otherwise just don't group `Price.select(:buy,:created_at).order(:created_at)`.